# form-horizontal not working with django-crispy-forms and django-registration-redux

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-forms, django-registration, django-crispy-forms

Disclaimer:  I'm a complete novice with Django and python.

I'm using crispy forms with django registration redux.  I've applied form-horizontal to a subclass of the registration form but it doesn't render with labels on same line as input fields as you can see here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/geYun.jpg

I've hard coded form-horizontal into the html in the template which shifts the form contents to the outside of the container:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUXKQ.jpg

I've tried creating a sublclass form called supplyhelixRegistrationForm that includes the label and field classes crispy forms docs says to include:  (Would include link but don't have enough reputation)

Part of forms.py from registration redux app that includes my modifications:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Div, Submit, HTML, Button, Row, Field
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import AppendedText, PrependedText, FormActions

User = UserModel()


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):


    required_css_class = 'required'
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (UsernameField(), "email")



class supplyhelixRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(supplyhelixRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()  
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
```

Then I modified the registration redux views.py to point to the supplyhelixRegistrationForm:

```
REGISTRATION_FORM_PATH = getattr(settings, 'REGISTRATION_FORM', 'registration.forms.supplyhelixRegistrationForm')
REGISTRATION_FORM = import_string( REGISTRATION_FORM_PATH )
```

And here's the template:

```
{% extends "registration/registration_base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy RegistrationForm RegistrationForm.helper %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Register for an account" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


<div class="container  vertical-center">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="panel  formBackground">

      <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <h2>Transform your supply chain today!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">


        <form  method="post" action="">
           {% csrf_token %}
           {{ form|crispy}}
           <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"  value="{% trans 'Register Now' %}" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forgot to mention:  I have crispy-forms installed per the docs.  Added the app to my project settings.py and included the bootstrap3 template pack as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is you're rendering the form with crispy templating, but because you're using it as a template variable (`{{ some_variable }}`)rather than using the `{% crispy form_name %}` tag the `FormHelper` attributes aren't getting applied properly.

Try these changes:

1. Replace `{{ form | crispy }}` with `{% crispy form %}`.
2. Add the following attribute to the `FormHelper` if you want to continue rendering the `<form></form>` tags manually:

`self.helper.form_tag = False`

3. You might need to remove the two lines that are currently attempting to manually create a `.form-horizontal` effect:

   `self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'`

   `self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'`

...DCF is automatically adding Bootstrap `.form-horizontal` CSS classes to your form, and these will likely interfere with those automatic additions.

Comment: YPCrumble, thanks for your quick reply!  I really appreciate it.  I made the changes you suggested and got the following:  http://imgur.com/F3nl7R7  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: One thing to try is removing `{% crispy RegistrationForm RegistrationForm.helper %}`. I haven't ever needed a tag like that and perhaps it's making your formatting odd. Other than that, it looks like a CSS issue now. The `.form-horizontal` class appears to be getting applied properly, correct? You'd have to post the HTML/CSS that's getting rendered to debug it, probably a separate question.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it was doing much.  Anyway, removed it with no change to output, unfortunately.

Comment: @WalterWhite updated my answer, you might want to remove the `col-lg-*`classes too

Comment: thanks  a lot for that feedback!  I removed and the render reverted to the original view.  But based on your suggestion, I changed the the field class to col-lg-10 so they added up to 12.  Got this:  http://imgur.com/Hfd2vE6   Now I'll play with the styling to add some padding.  Can't thank you enough.